# CALayer with All Gestures

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

i Have CALayer object called as root_layer and on the root_layer one_more subLayer is their, That sub_Layer i want apply the All Gestures to the sub_layer only. 
 Ex: Move, Rotation   please help me.

Thank.

Comment: You do know that CALayer doesn't participate in the event delivery right?

Answer (score 0):

`CALayer` just render for screen and can't get any gesture.You should handle the gesture by yourself.